# urls of all my pages have changed

Tags: wordpress, url, url-rewriting, google-plus

I don't know what I did but suddenly all my pages have a duplicate pages with the extension /google.com/+cormilubr (which is my website's google+ page).
I used screaming frog and it's showing me over 50 404 errors. Below an extract of screaming frog seo. You'll see all pages with 404 errors. They also exist without the extension and are code 200.
My website is http://cormilu.com.br

this is one of the duplicate urls that have appeared:
http://cormilu.com.br/google.com/+CormiluBr

Does anybody have an idea how this could have come upon so I can resolve it? I've deactivated all plugins , so this doesn't have anything to do with it. Pointing me in the right direction would be awesome!

Thanks a lot for you help.
Best regards,
Amir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in the footer of the website you have list of all your social networks. In the source of google plus link, you have added something like

```
google.com/+CormiluBr
```

Replace this with the exact url (with http://)

```
http://google.com/+CormiluBr
```

Here is the image with the link
[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you so much Omer for your help! This has been driving me nuts. Can't believe it was that simple.

Comment: glad to help :).  Mark the answer as correct to help others as well.